# (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00549: Failed to resolve server name for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (check DNS)

Tags: server, apache2, dns

I am trying to install **Localhost web-server** on my Ubuntu 18.04 by this instruction.

[How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04)

But by testing the `apach2` i get this error:

```
r$ sudo apache2ctl configtest
[Thu May 06 18:03:12.897955 2021] [core:error] [pid 22264] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00549: Failed to resolve server name for 192.168.1.12 (check DNS) -- or specify an explicit ServerName
Syntax OK
```

So i guess there must some conflict with others local-server installation like [publii](https://getpublii.com/) or [local](https://localwp.com/community/).

**Update:**

This is [the link of details](https://0bin.net/paste/Bbt7dljE#Kn4xBwmEfWwIAa+5S51XoeCrEhZaJ9sho0JigUZYHrX) on   `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file :

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like apache cannot determine you hosts "name" from your local DNS server, it uses the IP address of your server (192.168.1.12) to do a reverse lookup to get the name.  If your DNS server doesn't respond then you get this warning.

The apache config file does allow you to set the server name to a hardcoded value.  The config files are well commented and the ServerName option is near to the top.  mine is in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in the section Global Configuration.

Comment: i have Update the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you have a conflict. Apache is looking for a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) to route against, and you haven't set one. The message you're seeing is more a warning than anything. That said, the simplest way forward for a local installation is to provide an explicit ServerName.

Here's an easy way forward:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create/Edit `/etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf` using your preferred text editor. Be sure to do this with `sudo`, otherwise the file will not save.
2. Add the following line:

   ```
   ServerName my-machine.local
   ```

   Be sure to set `my-machine` to something you'd prefer if you'd rather the default FQDN be something else. There's no limits to what it can be, really. Then save the file and exit the editor.
3. Enable the Apache configuration:

   ```
   sudo a2enconf servername
   ```
4. Reload the Apache web server:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

This should eliminate the warning message.

Be sure to also set the `ServerName` variable in every VirtualHost block that you specify when creating configuration files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. By doing this you can make use of local DNS routing in `/etc/hosts` to better mimic a live website when testing/developing/working in the browser. Here is an example `.conf` file for a virtual host in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin your@email.addy
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website/public

        ServerName your-blog.local
        ServerAlias your-blog.local *.your-blog.local
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/blog-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/blog-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/website/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
</Directory>
```

Note the `ServerName` line in the configuration file. With this, you can edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add:

```
127.0.0.1    your-blog.local
```

After doing this, any time you type `your-blog.local` into a browser (on that machine), you will be redirected to the local site without needing to use an IP address or `http://localhost`. It's quite convenient.